# Somar Time convertendo para segundos em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando encontrar a diferença média entre a data de criação e ultima atualização dos registros de uma tabela da seguinte maneira:

```
tickets = Ticket.all.where('updated_at IS NOT NULL')
t = tickets.sum(:updated_at, conditions: 'updated_at.to_time') - tickets.sum(:created_at, conditions: 'created_at.to_time')
```

Mas deste modo está dando erro, onde estou errando?

Eu fiz desta maneira abaixo e funcionou; mas eu acredito que sem fazer este *loop* eu ganharia em performance.

```
tickets = current_client.tickets.where('updated_at IS NOT NULL')
t = 0
tickets.each do |ticket|
  t += ticket.updated_at.to_time - ticket.created_at.to_time
end
```

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado? Qual o resultado obtido?

Comment: O esperado seria a diferença média em segundos do **updated_at - created_at** mas ele não retorna nada, dá um erro de query.

Comment: Eu estava pensando num exemplo com dados reais. Se `a = b - c`, com `b` sendo 3 e `c` sendo 2, o esperado seria `1` mas `a` recebeu `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o problema é performance, faria a operação diretamente no BD:

```
Ticket.average("updated_at - created_at")
```

Havendo outras condições fica algo como:

```
Ticket.where(<suas condições>).average("updated_at - created_at")
```